# How to return all records with the latest datetime value [Postgreql]

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I return only the records with the latest upload_date(s) from the data below?

My data is as follows:

```
upload_date            |day_name |rows_added|row_count_delta|days_since_last_update|
-----------------------+---------+----------+---------------+----------------------+
2022-05-01 00:00:00.000|Sunday   |    526043|               |                      |
2022-05-02 00:00:00.000|Monday   |    467082|         -58961|                     1|
2022-05-02 15:58:54.094|Monday   |    421427|         -45655|                     0|
2022-05-02 18:19:22.894|Monday   |    421427|              0|                     0|
2022-05-03 16:54:04.136|Tuesday  |    496021|          74594|                     1|
2022-05-03 18:17:27.502|Tuesday  |    496021|              0|                     0|
2022-05-04 18:19:26.392|Wednesday|    487154|          -8867|                     1|
2022-05-05 18:18:15.277|Thursday |    489713|           2559|                     1|
2022-05-06 16:15:39.518|Friday   |    489713|              0|                     1|
2022-05-07 16:18:00.916|Saturday |    482955|          -6758|                     1|
```

My desired results should be:

```
upload_date            |day_name |rows_added|row_count_delta|days_since_last_update|
-----------------------+---------+----------+---------------+----------------------+
2022-05-01 00:00:00.000|Sunday   |    526043|               |                      |
2022-05-02 18:19:22.894|Monday   |    421427|              0|                     0|
2022-05-03 18:17:27.502|Tuesday  |    496021|              0|                     0|
2022-05-04 18:19:26.392|Wednesday|    487154|          -8867|                     1|
2022-05-05 18:18:15.277|Thursday |    489713|           2559|                     1|
2022-05-06 16:15:39.518|Friday   |    489713|              0|                     1|
2022-05-07 16:18:00.916|Saturday |    482955|          -6758|                     1|
```

NOTE only the latest upload_date for 2022-05-02 and 2022-05-03 should be in the result set.

Comment: If you are actually using this on a system, it would be better off just to insert the last upload of the day in an auxiliar table as the day ends, so you won't have to keep querying over and over the same table, as the data increases the query will get slower and slower as will the `INSERT` operation in an `INDEX`ed table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function to `PARTITION` by day (casting the timestamp to a date) and sort the results by most recent first by ordering by upload_date descending. Using `ROW_NUMBER()` it will assign a `1` to the most recent record per date. Then just filter on that row number. Note that I am assuming the datatype for upload_date is `TIMESTAMP` in this case.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    your_table.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(upload_date AS DATE) 
                       ORDER BY upload_date DESC) rownum 
  FROM your_table
)
WHERE rownum  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more verbose but I find it easier to read and build:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
JOIN (
    SELECT CAST(upload_date AS DATE) day_date, MAX(upload_date) max_date 
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY day_date) t2 
ON t1.upload_date = t2.max_date AND
    CAST(upload_date AS DATE) = t2.day_date;
```

I don't know about perfomance right away, but I suspect the window function is worse because you will need to `order by`, which is usually a slow operation unless your table already have an index for doing so.

Comment: This would only work for one week doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, now I get it, I didn't notice that he wanted for every day, I'll update.

Comment: Actually the question didn't specify if it want the last for each Day, or the last for each WeekDay, but I did it for each Day anyway.

Comment: I did run some tests here, @VvdL is faster if you have no `INDEX` at all, but if you create the index with something like `CREATE INDEX ix_mytable ON mytable USING BTREE(upload_date DESC, CAST(upload_date AS DATE))` then `JOIN` method will be faster.

Comment: agree, good addition

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e5dc1d00d46feba5a7ebc16a29997a86)

---

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        max(upload_date) OVER (PARTITION BY upload_date::date),
        upload_date,
        day_name,
        rows_added,
        row_count_delta,
        days_since_last_update
    FROM test101 ORDER BY 1
)
SELECT
    upload_date,
    day_name,
    rows_added,
    row_count_delta,
    days_since_last_update
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    max = upload_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('day', upload_date))
       to_char(upload_date, 'Day') AS weekday, *  -- added weekday optional
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY date_trunc('day', upload_date), upload_date DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7efec1ec3c67f9fbeda0cbc59d4cf810)*

For **few** rows per day (like your sample data suggests) it's the **simplest and fastest solution possible**. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

I dropped the redundant column `day_name` from the table. That's just a redundant representation of the `timestamp`. Storing it only adds cost and noise and opportunities for inconsistent data. If you need the weekday displayed, use `to_char(upload_date, 'Day') AS weekday` like demonstrated above.

The query works for any number of days, not restricted to 7 weekdays.